# Why is run.profiles getting ignored with spring-boot:run?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Using spring-boot-maven-plugin version 1.5.9.RELEASE. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html) states using -Drun.profiles to activate the active profiles. But running on the command line the profile is not activated:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=development
```

Using the jvmArguments parameter works and the profile is active:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=development"
```

Reference:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1095

**Update:**

It turned out, that the profile had been loaded correctly. Only the logging was disabled due to a conditional configuration of Logback:

In the Logback configuration I used a statement like `<if condition='property("spring.profiles.active").contains("development")'>`. Using the Maven plugin with `-Drun.profiles` does not set the system property `spring.profiles.active` but sets the command-line argument (`--spring.profiles.active`).

So, when using conditional statements in Logback only system properties and environment variables can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure do you have application-development.properties file. Else create it and put your properties there. By default application.properties will be considered and executed.

Based on the profile, you have create corresponding application properties file.